# My android app is automatically force closing

Tags: android

I have created an Android App for testing admob ads but when I run it, it force closes. 
My MainActivity:-

```
package com.dibdev.bmicalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class BMI_Calculator extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bmi__calculator);
}}
```

My Manifest. I do not think there is any error here.... :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.dibdev.bmicalculator"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <activity
        android:name=".BMI_Calculator"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

My Layout File. I have included xmlns...... in com.google...... Is it correct?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.dibdev.bmicalculator.BMI_Calculator" >

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="SAMPLE"
    ads:startOnCreate="True" >
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

My Logcat :-

```
11-08 14:37:58.161: I/System.out(25610): Sending WAIT chunk
11-08 14:37:58.161: W/ActivityThread(25610): Application com.dibdev.bmicalculator is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
11-08 14:37:58.176: I/dalvikvm(25610): Debugger is active
11-08 14:37:58.361: I/System.out(25610): Debugger has connected
11-08 14:37:58.456: I/System.out(25610): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-08 14:37:58.656: I/System.out(25610): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-08 14:37:58.856: I/System.out(25610): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-08 14:37:59.056: I/System.out(25610): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-08 14:37:59.256: I/System.out(25610): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-08 14:37:59.456: I/System.out(25610): waiting for debugger to settle...
11-08 14:37:59.661: I/System.out(25610): debugger has settled (1310)
11-08 14:37:59.681: E/dalvikvm(25610): dvmPauseGc(AppLaunch) called - cookie=0x47d7 (f=0x1)
11-08 14:37:59.691: I/PersonaManager(25610): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
11-08 14:37:59.741: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:48 height:48 bitmap id is 180 
11-08 14:37:59.751: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 181 
11-08 14:37:59.766: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 182 
11-08 14:37:59.781: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:13 height:41 bitmap id is 183 
11-08 14:37:59.786: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 184 
11-08 14:37:59.791: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 185 
11-08 14:37:59.801: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:18 height:18 bitmap id is 186 
11-08 14:37:59.836: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(25610): Parent view is not a TextView
11-08 14:37:59.861: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 187 
11-08 14:37:59.871: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 188 
11-08 14:37:59.881: D/skia(25610): GFXPNG PNG bitmap created width:72 height:72 bitmap id is 189 
11-08 14:37:59.911: W/dalvikvm(25610): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1355 (AdsAttrs) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
11-08 14:37:59.911: D/dalvikvm(25610): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0009
11-08 14:37:59.916: I/dalvikvm(25610): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x054c at 0x0f in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/bb;.<init>
11-08 14:37:59.916: I/dalvikvm(25610): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x054d at 0x15 in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/bb;.<init>
11-08 14:37:59.921: I/dalvikvm(25610): DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x054e at 0x32 in Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/bb;.<init>
11-08 14:38:00.911: D/dalvikvm(25610): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe the root cause is that you declared the same namespace twice: xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", delete this declaration from com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Comment: Have you defined a layout with the id **activity_bmi__calculator**, since you are using it in the **setContentView()** function.

Comment: post your log cat when you get error

Comment: @JibranKhan I have updated My question with LOGCAT.

Comment: @HassanAhmad What Do you mean?

Comment: @raj i have already posted.

Comment: run your app in normal mode without debunning mode then trace your logcat and post here

Comment: Try to replace this line xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" with xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" more details check :https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the activity closing tag of BMI_Calculator activity in your manifest.
If that's not it, please post the stacktrace.

Comment: May I know how to open Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

in latest ads sdk you need to add meta tag for gms version with ad declaration in menifest file which you forget to add.

integer value can be differ form your value, you can get it in your log cat while debunging.

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="6111000" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Comment: Sorry for delay but can you tell me how to get the value becz it now also force closing.